# Double integral dosen't give same result using Fubini Theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-domain, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I got the equation **0 < y $\le$ x < 1  $\iint k dxdy$ = 1** , where **k** is a **constant** but dosen't really matter ... My problem is that I've chose the domains of integration  **x $\in $** **( 0 , 1 )** and **y  $\in $**  **( 0 , x )**  thus I can write the integral in **2** ways **:**
**k**$\int_0^1\int_0^x 1 dydx = 1$ giveing me **k = 2** ... If I do the other way around **Fubini Theorem** says that I should get the same result but the **double integral** gives me **k*x = 1** thus makeing **k= 1 / x** ... Why ?

Comment: Could you edit in your calculations?

Comment: what do you mean ? To send my calculations in both ways ?

Comment: When I do the calculations, I don't get the problem you do, so you've just made a mistake we need to expose.

Answer (score 3):

On the one hand,$$\int_0^1\int_0^xdydx=\int_0^1xdx=\frac12.$$On the other hand,$$\int_0^1\int_y^1dxdy=\int_0^1(1-y)dy=\frac12.$$

Comment: I found the problem I didn't know the domain for x is from (y,1) ... But why you take it like that , that's what it confuses me ?

Comment: @VlAdTbK Because $0\le y\le x\le 1$ is equivalent to $0\le y\le x,\,0\le x\le 1$ (first approach) & $y\le x\le 1,\,0\le y\le 1$ (second approach).